# Vergessen = "to forget" AND "to forget about"?

Tags: verb

Kann man irgendwie auf eine Weise "forget about" sagen, die sich von einfach "vergessen" unterscheidet?  z.B.:

> **Mach dir keine Sorgen, Kleines!  Wir haben dich nicht vergessen!**  (gesagt zu einem weinenden Baby, das will, dass jemand auf es achtet.

Auf Englisch würde ich auch ab und zu sagen: *"Don't worry, baby!  We haven't forgotten **about** you!"*

Drückt man das auf Deutsch in gleicher Weise aus, oder kann man es irgendwie anders sagen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Verb `vergessen` wird im Deutschen für beide Bedeutungen (`to forget sth.` und `to forget about sth.`) genutzt. Der Bedeutungsunterschied muss sich aus dem Kontext ergeben.

Bei den positiven Antonymen von `vergessen` gibt es allerdings die Möglichkeit den Bedeutungsunterschied durch verschiedene Worte auszudrücken:

- `sich erinnern`
- `an etw./jmd. denken`
- (`auf etw./jmd. achten`)

Comment: ich habe meinen Kommentar wieder gelöscht um nicht Verwirrung zu stiften

Answer (score 2):

`about` is absolutely redundant here from a German point of view. Somehow you can compare it as if someone translates `sich mit Freunden treffen` to `to meet himself with friends`.

---

`about` ist völlig redundant hier aus deutscher Sicht. Du kannst es in etwa damit vergleichen, als ob jemand `sich mit Freunden treffen` mit `to meet himself with friends` übersetzt.

Comment: Die Frage war in Deutsch gestellt. Magst du deine Antwort übersetzen?

Comment: Das ist keine Redundanz, sondern ein modales Verb im Englischen. „to forget sth.“ und „to forget about sth.“ haben leicht verschiedene Bedeutungen.

Comment: das mit der Redundanz ist auch auf das deutsche Sprachempfinden bezogen (wie ich vielleicht etwas ungenau formuliert habe)